# spark streaming persistent table updates

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a spark structured streaming application (listening to kafka) that is also reading from a persistent table in s3 I am trying to have each microbatch check for updates to the table. I have tried

```
var myTable = spark.table("myTable!")
```

and

```
spark.sql("select * from parquet.`s3n://myFolder/`")
```

Both do not work in a streaming context. The issue is that the parquet file is changing at each update, and spark doesn't run any of the normal commands to refresh such as:

```
spark.catalog.refreshTable("myTable!")
spark.sqlContext.clearCache()
```

I have also tried:

```
spark.sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata","false")
  spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.cacheMetadata",false)
```

to no relief. There has to be a way to do this. Would it be smarter to use a jdbc connection to a Database instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will accomplish what I'm looking for.

```
val df1Schema = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("test1.csv").schema
    val df1 = spark.readStream.schema(df1Schema).option("header", "true").csv("/1")
    df1.writeStream.format("memory").outputMode("append").queryName("df1").start()

    var df1 = sql("select * from df1")
```

The downside is that its appending. getting around one issue is to remove duplicates based on ID and with the newest date.

```
val dfOrder = df1.orderBy(col("id"), col("updateTableTimestamp").desc)

val dfMax = dfOrder.groupBy(col("id")).agg(first("name").as("name"),first("updateTableTimestamp").as("updateTableTimestamp"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm reading you right I believe the issue is that because DataFrame's are immutable, you cannot see the changes to your parquet table unless you restart the streaming query and create a new DataFrame. This question has [come up on the Spark Mailing List before](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201705.mbox/%3C1493821832600-28642.post%40n3.nabble.com%3E). The definitive answer appears to be that the only way to capture these updates is to [restart the streaming query](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201705.mbox/%3CCA%2BAHuKn%2BvSEWkJD%3DbSSt6G5bDZDaS6wmN%2Bfwmn4jTm1X1nDAPA%40mail.gmail.com%3E). If your application cannot tolerate 10 second hiccups you might want to check out this blog post which summarizes the above conversation and discusses how [SnappyData enables mutations on Spark DataFrames](http://www.snappydata.io/blog/how-mutable-dataframes-improve-join-performance-spark-sql).

Disclaimer: I work for SnappyData

Comment: thanks, I'll have to take a look, read and test. I assume snappydata is a whole package Spark+ In memory database? If so that won't work for this use case.. it lives in AWS EMR. That being said I am always looking to find new options for future projects.

Comment: Hi Brian, SnappyData is an integration of Spark and an IMDB. There are a number of people using it in ["Smart Connector"](http://snappydatainc.github.io/snappydata/affinity_modes/connector_mode/) mode with an EMR cluster.

Comment: plambre,  any idea how to restart a streaming query?

Comment: I believe there are 2 other options I'm trying at the moment. One involves memorySink in the same application. The second uses kafka and log compaction. The hard part of the second option I thought of is that you must construct a single message based on the dataframe , and come up with a way to take that single message and then turn it into a dataframe. this seems actually very hard. again a single message.

Comment: so memory sink works fine if the dataframe isn't going to be that big.